Can i prevent / detect voice recording in React Native app (Android)?
I'm working on a React Native app that contains sensitive data (videos).
I need a way to prevent the user from using the phone's voice recorder and record the audio from the application.
the issue appears only on android.
I used this library to prevent video recording react-native-screen-guard
but i did not find a way to prevent voice recording.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to completely prevent voice recording on an Android device through a React Native app. This is because once the audio data leaves the device's microphone, it is no longer under the control of the app.
